# what shopping cart should we use for selling B2B SAAS software subscription

Tags: shopping-cart

We have a SAAS offering selling software service hosted at cloud. We are looking to enable the auto payment by allowing customers to pay for the service by using their credit card. The license model would be per user+per month or per user+per year. We are looking at using [Authorize.net](http://www.authorize.net/) for payment gateway and we are looking for shopping cart software as well before submitting the payment to Authorize.net. We looked at some of software at [Software Cart Software Review](http://shopping-cart-review.toptenreviews.com/), it seems most of those are for B2C selling physical items such as books.

Could we use that type of shopping cart software for B2B SAAS software subscription license model? It seems to me that this is not right shopping cart for our use case.  If you know other better recommendations, please let us know.